Tracking status changes over time
I am trying to track status changes over a given date range.  1/1/2023 - 1/31/2023
Table 1: Customer



filekey
activestatus
activestatuseffdate




1000
0
1/15/2023



Table 2: StatusHistory



filekey
status
effdate




1000
0
11/28/2022


1000
1
01/05/2023



The results I'm looking for are:










1/1/2023
1000
0


1/2/2023
1000
0


1/3/2023
1000
0


1/4/2023
1000
0


1/5/2023
1000
1


...




1/14/2023
1000
1


1/15/2023
1000
0


...




1/31/2023
1000
0



This is one of the many, many queries I've tried:
WITH StatusChanges AS (
  SELECT filekey, status, effdate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY filekey ORDER BY effdate) AS rn
  FROM empactstatushist
  WHERE filekey = 1000 AND effdate <= '2023-01-31'
),
Dates AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(day, n, '2023-01-01') AS DateValue
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1 AS n
    FROM sys.objects a
  ) AS n
  WHERE DATEADD(day, n, '2023-01-01') < '2023-02-01'
)
SELECT
  d.DateValue,
  filekey,
  sc.status
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN StatusChanges sc ON sc.filekey = 1000
  AND sc.effdate = (
    SELECT MAX(effdate)
    FROM StatusChanges sc2
    WHERE sc2.filekey = 1000 AND sc2.effdate <= d.DateValue
  );

But it doesn't give the results I need. How can I do this?

So what is your question..? You've told us what you are trying to do, but not what you are asking. What about what you've tried isn't working? What did you try? What about the content you read when you got stuck didn't you understand?

Sounds like you want to generate calendar view over changes in status, and where the final status is stored in some other table, which has been done gazillion times. A calendar table or similar and you should be in business. Btw, the MM-dd-yyyy format is the worst, dont' use it in any serious work

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

Are we really always looking for just one filekey?

nope, looking for them all.  this was just an example

See this db<>fiddle for another approach which calculates start/end date ranges for each status and expands the date range at the end. For larger data sets, it might have a slight performance edge, since it avoids the status lookup subquery.

Try this:
DECLARE @filekey int = 1000;
WITH StatusChanges AS (
   
    SELECT filekey, status, activestatuseffdate effdate 
    FROM Customer,
    WHERE filekey = @filekey AND activestatuseffdate < '20230201'
    UNION
    SELECT filekey, status, effdate
    FROM StatusHistory
    WHERE filekey = @filekey AND effdate < '20230201'
),
Dates AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(day, n, '20230101') AS DateValue
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1 AS n
    FROM sys.objects a
  ) AS n
  WHERE DATEADD(day, n, '20230101') < '20230201'
)
SELECT DateValue, @filekey,
   (
        SELECT TOP 1 status
        FROM StatusChanges
        WHERE Filekey = @filekey AND effdate <= DateValue
        ORDER BY effdate DESC  
   ) effdate 
FROM Dates
ORDER BY DateValue

And for all customer files:
WITH StatusChanges AS (
   
    SELECT filekey, status, activestatuseffdate effdate 
    FROM Customer,
    WHERE activestatuseffdate < '20230201'
    UNION
    SELECT filekey, status, effdate
    FROM StatusHistory
    WHERE effdate < '20230201'
),
Dates AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(day, n, '20230101') AS DateValue
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1 AS n
    FROM sys.objects a
  ) AS n
  WHERE DATEADD(day, n, '20230101') < '20230201'
),
DateKeys AS (
     SELECT DateValue, filekey
     FROM Dates
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT filekey FROM Customer) t
)
SELECT dk.DateValue, dk.filekey,
   (
        SELECT TOP 1 sc.status
        FROM StatusChanges sc
        WHERE sc.Filekey = dk.filekey AND sc.effdate <= dk.DateValue
        ORDER BY sc.effdate DESC  
   ) effdate 
FROM DateKeys dk

You'll want to add an ORDER BY to this, but it's not clear whether you want filekey or DateValue first.

this works for filekey=1000, how do I modify it to retrieve the same kind of data but for all relevant filekeys

@Green It's in the answer.

the filekey column is invalid in the 2 x dk.filekey and the filekey from dates is invalid as well

@Green Was missing a table alias for the cross join subquery.

That's it!  Thank you!
